# The Mathematics of the Cthulhu Cultus aliens called the Old Ones

Tags: aliens, h-p-lovecraft

Are the mathematics of the aliens called the Old Ones proposed by H.P. Lovecraft simply Fibonacci Mathematics?

The occultist Aleister Crowley proposed that a mathematics of Thelema  was hidden in his text the Book of the Law, and his student Kenneth Grant proposed an alignment of Lovecraft's Old Ones with more traditional occult symbolism. Lovecraft claimed that the mathematics of the Old Ones was based on a geometry of Five; 5 is the traditional occult number of the planet Mars: and Mars is the god Horus in Egyptian mythology. Crowley's text The Book of the Law  claims that humanity has now entered the Aeon of Horus.

I began researching this question when I discovered the Golden Ratio hidden  in the text of the Book of the Law: specifically, in verse 1.25, which of course can be read as the fraction 5/4ths, and 1/2(sq.rt.5/4)+1/2 equals the golden ratio. The mathematics of the Old Ones  has been written about in Lovecraft's story At the Mountains of Madness.

Comment: "Lovecraft claimed that the mathematics of the Old Ones was based on a geometry of Five" -- Are you sure Lovecraft claimed this? If so, where did he say it?

Answer (score 2):

HPL was an atheist, although with great imagination:

> “I am, indeed, an absolute materialist so far as actual belief goes; with not a shred of credence in any form of supernaturalism—religion, spiritualism, transcendentalism, metempsychosis, or immortality.” (H. P. Lovecraft, Selected Letters, Vol. II, p. 27)

in his books he never referenced any existing occult literature, even if (as an educated person) he definitely knew such names as Crowley or Blavatsky, all his books were purely made as a fiction literature.

[More on the topic](http://lovecraftnewsnetwork.blogspot.co.nz/2010/10/debunking-lovecraftian-occult.html)

Also, its worth to point that while HPL likes to use term "non-euclidean geomoetry" (I even [found a book trying to analyze his work from mathematical point of view](http://www.jstor.org/stable/25678597?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)) his real math skills were very basic - he failed math at school in 1908.

Comment: In "At the Mountains o adness", HPL mentions (on pps. 50, 51, 52, 55, & 56) A "...rampart, shaped like a star," "...masonry fully five feet thick," "five-pointed or five-ridged arrangements," "The ceaseless five-pointedness of the architecture," and "angles based upon the quantity of five." True, he was an atheist, but I'm only claiming that he dreamed about these things, NOT that he "believed" in them!

Comment: Old Ones have 5 tentacly arms, hence their maths is based on 5 (like we have 10 fingers so our maths is based on 10). Simple as that.